# Android Clear Cache Programatically not working

Tags: android, caching

I am trying to clear data and cache of my app programatically. Please find below the code for the same.

```
   public static void deleteCache(Context context) {
        try {

            File cache = context.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir();
            File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
            Log.d(TAG,appDir.getAbsolutePath());
            if (appDir.exists()) {
                String[] children = appDir.list();
                for (String s : children) {
                    if (!s.equals("lib")) {
                        deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));Log.i("TAG", "**************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/" + s + " DELETED *******************");
                    }
                }
            }

            File cache2= context.getApplicationContext().getExternalCacheDir();
            appDir = new File(cache2.getParent());
            Log.d(TAG,appDir.getAbsolutePath());
            if (appDir.exists()) {
                String[] children = appDir.list();
                for (String s : children) {
                    if (!s.equals("lib")) {
                        deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));Log.i("TAG", "**************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/" + s + " DELETED *******************");
                    }
                }
            }

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                File cache1 = context.getApplicationContext().getDataDir();
                 appDir = new File(cache1.getParent());
                Log.d(TAG,appDir.getAbsolutePath());

                if (appDir.exists()) {
                    String[] children = appDir.list();
                    for (String s : children) {
                        if (!s.equals("lib")) {
                            deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));Log.i("TAG", "**************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/" + s + " DELETED *******************");
                        }
                    }
                }

            }






        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    public static boolean deleteDir(File dir)
    {
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                if (!success) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return dir.delete();
    }
```

I have delete all file from getCacheDir, getExternalCacheDir and getDataDir. but still after running this code i can see my app cache size is still same. What should i do now ?

PFB Images where i am checking cache

[image: Cache Image]

PFB screenshot of manually clearing cache and storage:

[image: Manual cache clear]

Comment: Nothing, most likely. I do not know how you are checking the cache size, but it probably includes things that your app does not manage directly.

Comment: in the app info section i am checkinng the size of cache & user data its not getting cleared. but when i clicked on Clear cache & clear storage it becomes 0 kb

Comment: so when the app update i need to clear cache and data its not getting clear. i am checking this on Android 10 One Plus handset

Comment: @CommonsWare please have a look in updated question let me know what should i do

Comment: "but when i clicked on Clear cache & clear storage it becomes 0 kb" -- presumably, the OS is clearing things that you cannot access directly when you do that. "let me know what should i do " -- nothing. There are 26,000+ Android device models. What their editions of the Settings app shows is up to their device manufacturers. You do not control that. You can clear the contents of `getCacheDir()` and `getExternalCacheDir()` yourself. Other than that, leave the rest to the OS.